# Ошибка через 25 минут

Tags: c#

Не могу понять в чем проблема. Через 25 минут, если ПО в бездействии выбрасывает следующую ошибку в методе `get()`

> Переход к COM-контексту 0x8f8980 для данного объекта
>   RuntimeCallableWrapper завершился следующей ошибкой: Не удается
>   выполнить исходящий вызов, так как приложение обрабатывает входящий
>   синхронный вызов.

```
private string GetPortNumber()
        {
            using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                 new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                 "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity where caption like '%COM%' AND PNPDeviceID LIKE '%VID_05E0&PID_1701%' "))
            {
                string portNumber = "";

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {

                    string portName = (string)queryObj["Caption"];

                    if (portName.Contains("COM"))
                    {
                        portName = portName.Substring(portName.IndexOf('('));
                        portName = portName.Remove(portName.Length - 1);
                        portName = portName.Remove(0, 1);

                        portNumber = portName;
                    }
                }

                return portNumber;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Не совсем понял кто в бездействии: только ваша программа или вся система целиком? Просто некоторые системные службы довольно долго "просыпаются" после простоя системы - им нужно не которое время для повторной инициализации. Для локализации проблемы попробуйте добавить задержку в полсекунды в начале метода.

Comment: @rdorn ПО в бездействии, в системе работают.